# Where is "values" defined in a List of enum?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an `enum` and I can use `MyColors.values` on it but where this `values` is defined?

```dart
enum MyColor {
  red,
  blue,
  green,
}

enum MyNumbers {
  one,
  two,
  three,
}

void main() {
  getNames(MyColor.values);
  getNames(MyNumbers.values);
}

List<String> getNames(List<Enum> enums) {
  return enums.values.map((e) => e.name).toList(); // Error
}
```

How can I then use `values` myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enum MyColor { red, blue, green }` creates a special `MyColor` `Enum` class and creates compile-time constant *instances* of it named `red`, `blue`, and `green`. `values` is essentially an automatically generated `static` member.

From the **Enums** section of the Dart language specification:

[image]

(Sorry for using an image; reformatting it to Markdown is too impractical.)

> ```dart
> List<String> getNames(List<Enum> enums) {
>   return enums.values.map((e) => e.name).toList(); // Error
> }
> ```

Your `enums` parameter is a `List`, and `List` does not have a `value` member.  The callers of `getNames` already passed the list of `Enum` values.  You want:

```dart
List<String> getNames(List<Enum> enums) {
  return enums.map((e) => e.name).toList();
}
```

or:

```dart
List<String> getNames(List<Enum> enums) {
  return [for (var e in enums) e.name];
}
```

> what is `MyColor`, is this an `Enum` (no), is this a `List<Enum>`, again no?

`MyColor` itself is a `Type`, just like `int` or `double` or `String` or `List`.

`MyColor.red` is a compile-time constant *instance* of a `MyColor`. `MyColor.red is MyColor` and `MyColor.red is Enum` are both true.

This is not fundamentally different from:

```dart
class Base {}
class Derived extends Base {}
```

`Derived` and `Base` are `Type` objects.  `Derived is Base` is false (a `Type` object is not an instance of `Base`).  However, `Derived() is Base` is true.